# Angular form submitted with errors

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using Angular 13.2.6 with ionic framework(5.4.16). I am using Reactive Forms with a small form preloaded with values to allow the user to update the details but when I submit the form it does not show validation errors and get submitted with following error in console:

core.mjs:6485 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userName')
at ProfilePage_form_5_Template (template.html:52:48)

Form in profile.page.html is as shown below:

```
<form *ngIf="profileLoaded" [formGroup]="editProfileForm" (ngSubmit)="submitProfileForm()" novalidate>
    <ion-item lines="full">
      <ion-label position="floating">Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" name="userName" [ngModel]="profile.userName" class="form-group" formControlName="userName" value=""></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <span class="error ion-padding" *ngIf="isSubmitted && errorControl.userName.errors?.required">
      Name is required.
    </span>
    <ion-item lines="full">
      <ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="email" name="userEmail" [ngModel]="profile.userEmail" class="form-group" formControlName="userEmail" value=""></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <span class="error ion-padding" *ngIf="isSubmitted && errorControl.userEmail.errors?.pattern">
      Invalid email.
    </span>
    <ion-item lines="full">
      <ion-label position="floating">Contact</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" name="userContactNumber" [ngModel]="profile.userContactNumber" class="form-group" formControlName="userContactNumber" value=""></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item lines="full">
      <ion-label position="floating">Address</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" name="userAddress" [ngModel]="profile.userAddress" class="form-group" formControlName="userAddress" value=""></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-button type="submit" expand="block">Save Changes</ion-button>
 </form>
```

Form builder code in profile.page.ts

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
 
export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {
  
  editProfileForm: FormGroup;

  this.isSubmitted = true;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {}

    async ngOnInit() {
        this.editProfileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
           userName: ['', [Validators.required]],
           userEmail: ['', [Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$")]],
           userContactNumber: [''],
           userAddress: ['']
        });
    }



   async submitProfileForm() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    if(!this.editProfileForm.valid) {
      console.log(`Invalid values`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Submit success`);
    }

}
```

I have

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

in profile.module.ts file. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: If you use Reactive Form, you shouldn't use `ngModel`. Can you highlight with line where you get the following error? And where is the `errorControl` come from?

Comment: That was it man, I forgot to define function errorControl

Comment: get errorControl() {
    return this.editProfileForm.controls;
  }

Comment: Does your issue solved?

Comment: Yong Shun yes defining that function which you pointed out solved the problem. Thanks.